# MacOS keyboard mapping in Windows VMWare Guest

Tags: mac, keyboard, vmware-fusion

I have been tryign to resolve an issue with keyboard mapping from a MacOS host to a VMWare Windows 10 guest OS to no avail.

The configuration is a UK Layout Corsair K70 connected to the Mac host, with a Windows 10 guest running in VMWare.

The keyboard is mapped correctly in MacOS, with the UK PC keyboard profile selected.
All keys return the correct character.

When using Windows 10 in VMWare, the mapping is incorrect - \ maps to ` and vice versa.

I have tried all UK keyboard profiles in the guest Windows OS, but the mapping is unchanged.

The Macbook keyboard is also incorrectly mapped, which is even more puzzling as regardless of which keyboard profile is selected in macOS, the windows guest OS key mapping is unaffected, suggesting VMWare is altering it at some stage.

When setting the keyboard in VMWare to Staright Throguh, I would expect the characters types on the host OS to be passed straight through the the guest.

Any suggestions of how to narrow the issue down would be appreciated.

The host OS is macOS 10.12.2 Sierra
Guest OS is Windows 10 Pro
VMWare version is Fusion Pro 8.5.5 (5192483).

Many thanks